# Glossary of mobile app development terms

Tags: iphone, android

Does Apple or anyone have a glossary of terms used in iphone and android app development?  Screens, Skins, Pages...all names I have seen used for the same thing. I really want a list of tech terms for all aspects of a mobile app. That way, idea guy and developer guy don't spend 20 emails and 3 days figuring out that they are saying the same thing.

Comment: You assume that there is a universal cross-platform definition of such terms. AFAIK, you are sorely mistaken.

Comment: Agree with CommonsWare, there definitely isn't a common-thread to both iOS and Android, outside of pretty much the handset itself.  I would just dig a little and screenshot/label like a mad man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is different for Android and iOs, they are based on different languages, have different GUI frameworks developed by two different groups of people. They will not match up at all.

To learn the lingo I suggest reading the official SDK documentation and they will introduce much of the top level terminology to you.

Android:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

iOS:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW14

If you are really interested in this you can look for a nice GUI theory book but everyone has their own theories and there is no accepted definition.

Some resources:

- http://java.sun.com/docs/glossary.html
- http://www.classicsys.com/css06/cfm/glossary.cfm